# Streaming from gopro to android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, stream, gopro

I'm try to send the video stream from gopro to android. 
I connect and manage the gopro via http thanks to guide of KonradIt https://github.com/KonradIT/goprowifihack
With ffmpeg android library we managed the streaming
http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/
but i can see only the information about the frame and i can send the 
stream to my computer (attacched to gopro) and see it with vlc. 
The ffmpeg command launched from the application android is:

ffmpeg -an -f:v mpegts -i udp://:8554 -an -f:v mpegts udp://10.5.5.101:8555

But we want see the stream directly on app android.

How can do it?